# Number of iterations to cover all random numbers

Tags: c, random, probability

I read the answers to the various questions on how to generate random numbers between 0 and 1.

`float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;`

Now I'm curious. Considering that the generator repeats the numbers (for a truly random number), how many iterations do you think makes it cover almost all possibilities. 
I code in C and use the gcc compiler.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "almost"?

Comment: I said almost because I do not know whether it covers all :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a *true* random number generator (i.e. the probability of drawing a given number is `1 / RAND_MAX` and independent of the previous drawn set of numbers), then you'd need an infinite number of iterations to cover all possibilities.

`rand()` however will recover all iterations in `RAND_MAX` trials if it's implemented as a linear congruential generator with *periodicity* of `RAND_MAX` (as it frequently is).

Comment: Even with a true RNG, you only have a finite set of possible values (as `float` is limited). Consequently, you certainly obtain all possible values if you try often enough.

Comment: Indeed, but only after an infinite number of trials. That result is independent of the set of possible values, excepting the trivial case of just one possibility. Of course this is only for a "true" RNG.

Comment: ... if you want to be sure to have obtained **all** values, yes. But OP is asking "how many iterations do you think makes it cover almost all possibilities". I understood he is asking for an answer like: After 2**64 samples, with 95% certainty you have seen 90% of the values. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Sort of moot since the LC generator will recover all values within `RAND_MAX`. The analysis of a true generator is more of a mathematical question: the answer is that the probability of attaining a certain set of drawings is distributed as a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 3):

The `rand()` function uses some internal memory. If it uses `b` bits of memory then it cannot have more than `2^b` different states. This means the sequence will repeat with a period inferior to `2^b`.

For Posix it is specified the sequence will **not** repeat with a period inferior to `2^32` (which is a stricter constraint than my first point).

Now if you're only interested in the length of a sequence that contains at least twice the same number, then it is obviously `RAND_MAX+1` because of the pigeonhole principle.

**References**

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rand.html

Comment: Please explain the downvote. If you think something is wrong, share it to enlighten everyone, not just you.

Comment: My downvote was because your answer did not fit to my interpretation of the question (see comments to Bathsheba's answer). In fact, the question is quite ambigous. Therefore I revert the downvote. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably impossible to say.

The only close way to determine it would be to run tests, (using your random function untill all values are found), and counting the number of iterations. Then you do it a lot of times and determine the average...